# String comparison '1111' < '99' is True

Tags: python

There is something wrong if you compare two string like this:

```
>>> "1111">'19'
False
>>> "1111"<'19'
True
```

Why is '1111' less than than '19'?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because strings are compared [*lexicographically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). `'1'` is smaller than `'9'` (comes earlier in the character set). It doesn't matter that there are other characters after that.

If you want to compare *numbers* you have to convert the string to a number first:

```
>>> int('1111') > int('19')
True
```

otherwise this is comparing exactly like you'd compare dictionary words; `Aaaa` is smaller than `Ab`

Answer (score 2):

Because strings are compared [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

That is first the first character is compared, in this case - `'1'` and `'1'` - as they are same they move on to the next character.

In the next character - `'1'` is less than `'9'` , hence `'1111'` is less than `'19'` .

Answer (score 0):

Use `type()` to check the type of the token:

```
type("1111")
```

Output:

```
str
```

It's a string. Hence it will be compared lexicographically.